# Thrift serialization/deserialization issue with list in java

Tags: java, thrift

I have a Thrift struct, which contains list and I am serializing the struct in Java, and when I deserialize the list are different from the values which I serialized.

In another stackoverflow post, it is mentioned that TBinaryProtocol has the issue with thrift versions less than 0.4.0. But it seems to be an issue with 0.8.0 version as well.

Is there anyway to overcome this problem?

Comment: Please improve your question by providing the code, the expected output, the error (Stacktrace, logs etc) and a link to the other post in SO that you mentioned.

Comment: In addition to what alfasin said, always try against a mpore recent version as well. Older versions are not really maintained actively (although that does not answer the question, I know).